# How to use variables in Matlab App Designer in all callbacks

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I have different callbacks in an Matlab App Designer App. In my case several buttons. I need to use the same variables for that.

I only get an error when using a variable I created in one Callback in another...

Comment: Could you post some of the code

Comment: There is no need here, as the code Shows only normal Matlab coding with normal use of variables. I don't know how to use variables in App Designer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I got your problem.

The easiest way is in beginning to create a new property (red button on the top left in EDITOR) and use it as a variable throughout the code.

Be careful to use `app.variablename` to address the variable.

If your code is already finished and you just discovered that error, you can set properties for only the variables you need to exchange and then get them like this:

set property:

```
properties (Access = private)
     varone %first variable
     vartwo % second variable
     ...
end
```

get Data for Exchange:

```
varone = app.varone; %(now you can use varone instead of app.varone)
```

make it public again at the end of your callback:

```
app.varone = varone;
```

Comment: Thx...
That's what I was looking for...
Excuse my dumn easy question